# List variable that is set to one list or another depending on condition

Tags: list

I am trying to create a list variable that can be set to one list or another depending on a condition. What I have so far is as follows.

```
(let ((l (if local list1 list2)))
  ; Append items to the list
  )
```

- `local` is a parameter that can be set to `t` or `nil`.
- `list1` and `list2` are list variables.

Then when I later try to access either list1 or list2, I am getting the following error.

```
Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument sequencep t)
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is update either list1 or list2 depending on the value of local. Perhaps this is what is causing my issue.

The following is the shortest code segment that illustrates the problem.

```
(defvar local-list '())
(defvar global-list '())

(defun add-item-to-list (local item)
  (let ((l (if local local-list global-list)))
    (add-to-list 'l item)
    )
  )

(defun print-local-list ()
  (mapc (lambda (item) (message item)) local-list)
  )

(add-item-to-list t "Blue")
(add-item-to-list t "Greem")
(add-item-to-list t "Red")
(print-local-list)
```

Comment: You need to add some information to replicate your issue. What function are you calling and what is the value of list1, local, list2, etc. try to create a code snippet that someone else can take and run.

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to `t` and examine the stack.

Comment: Please show the code that uses `l` and expects a sequence.

Comment: Copy-paste a [complete code fragment that reproduces the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is no problem in the code you show and we can't guess what you aren't showing.

Comment: After Ben Key has added a minimal example the problem is clear. The quoting in `add-item-to-list` is in the wrong order. `local-list` and `global-list` should be quoted not `l`. Therefore I vote to re-open the question.

Comment: I just tried your sample code but it did not signal any error (hence not the `Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument sequencep t)` you mention).  Side note: `(lambda (item) (message item))` can be advantageously replaced with `#'message` (that's called an eta-reduction).

Comment: @Stefan You are right that `Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument sequencep t)` does not happen with his minimal example. Nevertheless the error shows up in the way that `(print-local-list)` prints nothing. `local-list` is empty. About your side note: `#'message` is dangerous since its first argument is the format string. `#'princ` or `(lambda (item) (message "%s" item))` is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign **the value** of `local-list` or `global-list` to the local variable `l`. Later you apply `add-to-list` **to that local variable** `l`. By default `add-to-list` prepends the new item to the list. That means a new first link is created and assigned to `l`. That does not change the list values of `local-list` nor `global-list`.  (Note, if the value of `l` is `nil` it does not matter whether you prepend or append the new item.)

What you probably want is to assign one of the symbols `local-list` or `global-list` to `l` and use that selected symbol for `add-to-list`. In the following code the quote is shifted from `add-to-list` to the value of `l`. Thus `l` evaluates to one of the symbols `local-list` or `global-list` in the call of `add-to-list` and the new item is added to the list value of the resulting symbol (`local-list` or `global-list`).

Note also that `(message item)` is dangerous. The string `item` is interpreted as format string. If it contains a percent sign the character sequence after the percent sign is misinterpreted as format specifier. It is better to use `#'princ` or `(lambda (item) (message "%s" item))`.

```el
(defvar local-list '())
(defvar global-list '())

(defun add-item-to-list (local item)
  (let ((l (if local 'local-list 'global-list)))
    (add-to-list l item)
    )
  )

(defun print-local-list ()
  (mapc #'princ local-list)
  )

(add-item-to-list t "Blue")
(add-item-to-list t "Greem")
(add-item-to-list t "Red")
(print-local-list)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I needed to know.